# ketcher-react package Using in NextJs 14 and having issues with internal import of css

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js, node-modules

When I try to use the module in NextJs 14 project, I'm constantly getting an error message:
./node_modules/draft-js/dist/Draft.css
Global CSS cannot be imported from within node_modules.

Is there a way to use Ketcher with NextJs? I couldn't find a single way to make it run, mainly because of this CSS issue.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U96a4.png)

I haven't been able to find a solution. It seems to be causing some roadblocks in my project development. If you have any insights or solutions on how to resolve this issue, I would greatly appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Please post the error as text, and not an image.